# How to change position of the View Controller on screen orientation change in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to create iOS application which have Header,Container and Footer just like iOS default Camera app have. Header have title and footer have 4 buttons and Container load url in UIWebView. Now when i change orientation of the screen i want that header come to top and container below header and footer will come to right side of the screen with horizontal button. How can i achieve this effect in iOS 7.

Here is a screen shot how my app look like in Portrait and in Landscape.
[image][image]

I tried UIStackView but it only support iOS9+ and i also try to use OAStackView but its not working properly. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you find the solution for your problem?, Let me know if you can achieve it through my solution or if it in some other way

Comment: There is no use for this conversation, if you are not reply

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is you should have two footer views one at the bottom and other at the right side of the view,

set the hidden property for the footer view based on the orientation,

change the size of the container view in the method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

*if(PORTRAIT){

    self.containerview.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.orign.x, self.headerview.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-footer.view.frame.size.height);

    rightSideFooterView.hidden = YES;
    bottomFooterView.hidden = NO;

else {

self.containerview.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.headerview.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width-footer.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
rightSideFooterView.hidden = NO;
bottomFooterView.hidden = YES;
}*
```

I think this may solve your problem, am not sure this is the best way but this is one of the way to handle this

Comment: Thanks for you replay, is there any other way to achieve this using single footer view?

Comment: @NishitPatel May be there is some way, but when your are using autolayout through storyboard, you can't get your expected view but if you have enough knowledge in auto layout through coding may be it will

Comment: when your are using autolayout its fully based on top left bottom right constraints so when you change the orientation the view will be adjusted based on these constraints so its not possible to get your expected layout when you are using auto layout through storyboard

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @NishitPatel All the best, If you feel this answer gives a solution to your problem , just mark it as correct , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For the tool bar, I will design two custom tool bars. For example, `toolBarL` for landscape, and `toolBarP` for portrait.

When in landscape, let `toolBarL` show and hidden `toolBarP`. And in portrait mode, show `toolBarP` and hidden `toolBarL`.

Override the method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` of `UIViewController` for rotating orientation.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        // UI for portrait 
    } else {
        // UI for landscape
    }
}
```